Create a final list of dict from list containing dict
If the code AND land are the same then add this dict part to final.
Next if the next dict part has the same code and land,but different size and value as the previous one, then add size and value to the previous one,while every other part of the dict stays the same.
If code AND land are not the same then skip and add as a new dict to final.
So, in the end it should look like this:
final = [
    {
        "size": 2,  # size changed
        "code": "330",
        "content": "xyz",
        "land": "AB",
        "value": 15  # value changed
    },
    {
        "size": 1,
        "code": "400",
        "content": "abc",
        "land": "KK",
        "value": 12
    }
]

I tried this code. But it just adds the dicts.
My code so far:
import json

mylist = [
    {
        "size": 1,
        "code": "300",
        "content": "xyz",
        "land": "AB",
        "value": 5
    },
    {
        "size": 1,
        "code": "300",
        "name": "xyz",
        "land": "AB",
        "value": 10
    },
    {
        "size": 1,
        "code": "400",
        "content": "abc",
        "land": "KK",
        "value": 12
    }
]

final = []

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if mylist[i]["code"] == "300" and mylist[i]["land"] == "AB":
        # here should be logical decision
        final.append(mylist[i])
    elif mylist[i]["code"] == "400" and mylist[i]["land"] == "KK":
        final.append(mylist[i])

with open('stackoverflowResponse.json', 'w') as resp:
    json.dump(final, resp, indent=2)


You can remove the JSON stuff; it doesn't really have anything to do with your actual question.

Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's no question here. What do you need help with exactly? Maybe you want to ask something like "How can I group dicts together", but questions like that have already been asked, like How do I group this list of dicts by the same month? Check out [ask], and you can [edit] to clarify.

In one of your input dicts, you have name instead of content. Is that a typo? Or should that be ignored by the code?

Your output has "code": "330", instead of "code": "300",. Is that a typo?

Yes, sorry that a typo, in Final = [] "code" should be 300. And in mylist @position 1 instead of "name", it should be "content".

Try using a variable to see if this criteria already exists:
final = []

exist = False
index = 0

for i in mylist:
    
    if i["code"] == "300" and i["land"] == "AB":
            if not exist:
                index = len(final)
                final.append(i)
                exist = True
            if exist:
                final[index]['code'] = str(int(final[index]['code']) + int(i["code"]))
                final[index]['size'] = str(int(final[index]['size']) + int(i["size"]))
                final[index]['value'] += i["value"]

    elif i["code"] == "400" and i["land"] == "KK":
            final.append(i)

    else:
          pass


Hi U-13. Thanks for the response. But I'm getting IndexError: list index out of range error

@SirSkywalker Updated my answer! You can upvote the answers if they help! Also if e-motta's answer helped, you can accept it

You can use this:
final = []

for entry in mylist:
    for final_entry in final:
        if (
            entry["code"] == final_entry["code"]
            and entry["land"] == final_entry["land"]
        ):
            final_entry["size"] += entry["size"]
            final_entry["value"] += entry["value"]
            break
    else:
        final.append(entry)

[
    {"size": 2, "code": "300", "content": "xyz", "land": "AB", "value": 15},
    {"size": 1, "code": "400", "content": "abc", "land": "KK", "value": 12},
]


Wow, this worked like charm. Thank you very much :)
